# Setting char array length with strlen() returns wrong size

Tags: c

I am trying to create a new c-string with the length of a passed in c-string. I set a variable to the length of the old string and then try to set a new c-string with that length but checking that length returns 1. Why does this happen?

```
//This function will return a pointer to a char array
char *encrypt(char plainText[], char code[]){
    int i = 0,j = 0;
    //length of plainText
    int len = strlen(plainText);
    printf("len %i\n",len); //8
    //I am declaring a pointer here
    char *x;
    //make a string for the cipherText
    char cipher[len];
    printf("cipher %lu\n",strlen(cipher)); //1
    return "Nothing";
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `sizeof(cipher)`?

Comment: It's probably better to use `char*` in preference to `char[]` for consistency's sake here.

Comment: You define `x`; you never use it.  You define `cipher`; you never initialize it.  You don't make `cipher` big enough to hold the null byte at the end of a string.  The length of a string does not include the null byte, though the "value" of the string does include it (at least, the string ends at the first null byte).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you. I apologize, this was from a big function I cut down to try and isolate this question and in haste left some mess. I've been really confused on how to initialize a c-string of the same size as the string I pass in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `cipher` is *uninitialized*. It's contents is *indeterminate* (and will seem almost random). It might not contain the string-terminator at all, which means `strlen` will go out of bounds in its search for it. In your specific case you seem to be "lucky" that the second element in your array just happens to be the terminator.

And you seem to forget that `char` strings are really called ***null-terminated*** byte strings. That *null-terminator* also needs space. And exist of course.

All in all plenty of chances for [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: That and `cipher` goes out of scope the moment that function ends, so it can't be returned.

Comment: There is no "chance" for undefined behaviour. Either it is UB or it isn't.

Comment: @Ctx: While a particular code path with particular data might deterministically have behavior not defined by the C standard or not, it can be non-deterministic whether the code goes down that path with that data. For example, if a jump is conditional on indeterminate data, it might or might not go down a path with behavior not defined by the C standard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm confused now because I've seen code like `char myString[10];` That makes space for 10 characters, with the last being a null terminated string. I thought that since I was passing 8 into the brackets I'd be making space in memory for an 8 char array?

Comment: @EricPostpischil, its behavior will be 100% deterministic. We just won't be able to predict what it is.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Randomness is deliberately injected into processes nowadays, as with Address Space Layout Randomization, and that randomness is fed with thermal noise and other sources of entropy.

Comment: @NoleloN "...I thought that since I was passing 8 into the brackets ..." is not supported by the post.  Edit into a [MCVE]

Comment: @NoleloN An array of eight elements can store a string of *seven* characters. If you want a string of `len` characters, then you need an array of `len + 1` elements, to be able to fit the terminator. And you need to initialize the array before you start passing it around.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Undefined behaviour is invoked by a certain code pattern and the actual behaviour is completely independent of this. Your statements are completely irrelevant with regard to this

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: An array of eight `char` can store eight `char`. Generally, cryptographic code does not use null-terminated strings for ciphertext, because the bytes of ciphertext are arbitrary values generated by the encryption algorithm, so some of them will be zero values. Use fixed-length blocks is common in cryptographic code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True, but in this case the OP is using the array as a null-terminated string (passing it to `strlen`).

Comment: @Ctx: The C standard specifies several types of incompletely specified behavior, of which undefined behavior is only one. There are also implementation-defined behavior and unspecified values (C 2011 3.19.3). Code could depend on unspecified values in such a way that some branches yield defined behavior and some branches do not. Hence, it is effectively chance whether a branch to defined behavior or a branch to undefined behavior is taken.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Yes, but the likely fix is not to use `strlen`, rather than to try appending a null terminator to data that may contain internal zeros.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This sounds a bit constructed... DR451 states, that "library functions will exhibit undefined behavior when used on indeterminate values" and J.2 states, that "The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances: The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate". There isn't much room left for your argumentation.

Comment: @Ctx: You may consider it “constructed” if you wish, whatever that means, but such an opinion has no bearing on the truth of the assertion that undefined behavior cannot happen by chance. It is false. As simple code as `unsigned char a[9]; if (a[9]) RoutineWithUndefinedBehavior();` is, as far as the C standard is concerned, non-deterministically defined or undefined, and it avoids both of your points about library routines or objects with automatic storage duration. (The full rule for the latter excludes objects that cannot be declared with `register`, thus excluding array elements.)

Comment: Correction: I intended `if (a[4])…`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This claim collides with the statement in the standard J.2 which says, that "The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances: The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate".

Comment: @Ctx: Annex J is not a normative part of the standard. It is a summary. Read the actual rule in 6.3.2.1 2. It only applies to objects that could have been declared with `register`.